# Export drop down selected values in a Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, export-to-excel

I am currently displaying table corresponding to each user as follows.

[image]

Want to export the selected values to an excel sheet. Normal export functionality of datatables is exporting all values of dropdown, so i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817432/datatables-export-to-excel-select-option/53104566) link for exporting dropdown selected values.

For the above link solution to work, the **dropdown**  tag must contain **selected** attribute but **in my case "selected" is not present anywhere in the  tag** as i am setting the dropdown value using the following piece of line. so, by default the first value in dropdown is getting exported.

```
document.getElementById(drp_id).value = "firstname"
```

Please suggest a workaround for exporting this data to an excel.

Comment: Hard to debug an image.