# Datatables export excel and pdf data format issue

Tags: jquery, datatables, codeigniter-3, x-editable

i am using datatable server-side with codeigniter, i fetch data and integrate x-editable to inline edit. i added export button, when i print that is fine, but when i export data in pdf and excel that's not correct in format. i m getting like this pdf:
[image]

anchor for edit inline data also comes with export in pdf same issue with excel.

Comment: See this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329997/export-data-from-datatable-with-select-element-exports-each-option-from-the-sele you basically do the same, just extract textContent from `<a>` tags instead of `<selects>`

Comment: this is not working giving error in console
Cannot read property 'anCells' of undefined

Comment: As long as you not share your code, no one is able to help you out. Or willing to.